# float right does not work with min width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to align an image to the right and the text to the left. It works but its not responsive with min-width.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnn2yg5k/5/

Notice if I put an image/div to the left instead the min-width works and keeps the text together. I'm using the same code in both cases: float right and left.

```
<h2>Image on the left</h2>
<div class="leftImage">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="textRight">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rutrum purus a diam congue, facilisis                   interdum nunc dictum. In quis felis non libero dignissim hendrerit. Curabitur at iaculis massa. </p>
  </div>
</div>
<h2> Image to the right</h2>
<div class="rightImage">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="textLeft">
     <p>Loremmm ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rutrum purus a diam congue, facilisis                 interdum nunc dictum. In quis felis non libero dignissim hendrerit. Curabitur at iaculis massa. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.leftImage{
  margin-top: 20px;
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height: 500px;
}
.rightImage{
  margin-top: 20px;
  float:right;
  width:300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.textRight{
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  height:150px;
  padding: 80px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 120px; 
  margin-left: 250px; 
}
.textLeft{
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  height:150px;
  padding: 80px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  margin-right: 250px; 
}
#wrap{
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 900px;
}
```

Any idea how I can fix it for the div to the right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive img width use **max-width:900px** and **width:100%** 
Only problem here is you are using min-width so it can not be smaller then 900px;

HTML - is the same

```
        <h2>
          Imageto the right
        </h2>

        <div id="wrap">
          <div class="rightImage">
              <div class="image"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="textLeft">
            <p>Loremmm ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
             Nullam rutrum purus a diam congue, facilisis interdum nunc 
             dictum. In quis felis non libero dignissim hendrerit. Curabitur 
             at iaculis massa. 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS - change is in #wrap max-width:900px;

```
/* Carta/Menu */
 .image{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
 /*.leftImage{
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height: 500px;
} */
.rightImage{
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.textRight{
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    height:150px;
    padding: 80px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 120px; 
    margin-left: 250px; 
}
.textLeft{
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    height:150px;
    padding: 80px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    margin-right: 250px; 

}
#wrap{
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```